# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $3^n+5^n = x^3$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all positive integers $n$ such that $3^n+5^n = x^3$ for some positive integer $x$.

One solution is $n = 1, x = 2$.

We have $1 < 3^n+5^n \leq 8^n$, so $1 < 3^n+5^n \leq 2^{3n}$. Thus $1 < x \leq 2^n$. How can we continue from here?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: A starting point is that the left side is always even (because each term is always odd), so the right side is even, hence $x$ is even, hence the left side is always divisible by $8$.  Working mod 8, the equation then becomes $3^n+(-3)^n\equiv 0 \pmod 8$, so $n$ must be odd.  Working mod other things might give more information.

Comment: To give an example, mod 7 (chosen because 7-1 is a multiple of 3, which is necessary for not every number to be a cube mod p), the the only cubes are -1,0, 1, and so combing the fact that $n$ is odd with Euler's theorem and some computations mod 7, we get that $n$ is not divisible by 3 and that $x^3\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  Working mod 13, we see that n=1, 5 mod 12, and $x^3\equiv 1, 8 \pmod{13}$.

Comment: @Aaron Taking modulo $9$ I get $5^n \equiv x^3 \pmod{9}$. Since $5^n \equiv 2,5,8 \pmod{9}$ since $n$ is odd, it follows that $x^3 \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$. Thus, $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @user19405892 Let me verify your calculations.  I think you may have essentially shown that there are no solutions other than $n=1$.

Comment: $n$ cannot be divisible by $3$ as that would reduce to FLT for $n=3$.

Answer (score 4):

Modulo $9$, if $n>1$, the equation simplifies to $5^n\equiv x^3 \pmod 9$.  Because the cubes mod 9 are $0,1,8$, and $5^n \pmod 9$ repeats with period $\phi(9)=6$ with the pattern (starting at $n=0$) $1,5,7,8,4,2,\ldots$, we have that $n$ is a multiple of $3$ (if $n>1$).

However, working modulo $7$, where $3^n+5^n$ also has period $\phi(7)=6$, we see that $3^{3k}+5^{3k}$ is never a cube mod 7. (The cubes are 0,1,6, and $3^n+5^n$ repeats $2,1,6,5,6,1,\ldots,$ but neither $2$ nor $5$ are cubes).

Therefore, if $n>1$, combining both results, we see there are no solutions.  However, $n=1, x=2$ is a solution.  Hence, it is the only solution.

Comment: $n$ cannot be divisible by $3$ as that would reduce to FLT for $n=3$. And so proof ends after first paragraph...

Comment: @sku Haha, how right you are!  However, I try not to use theorems that I can't prove in MSE answers.